# heroku local web doesn't work because of gunicorn connection in use

Tags: python, django, heroku, wsgi, gunicorn

I have cloned this heroku-django-starter https://github.com/heroku/heroku-django-template.

I have done `pip install gunicorn`

When i run `heroku local web`, i'm getting the following error log.

```
forego | starting web.1 on port 5000
web.1  | [2016-03-08 21:03:59 -0800] [8288] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.4.5
web.1  | [2016-03-08 21:03:59 -0800] [8288] [ERROR] Connection in use: ('0.0.0.0', 5000)
web.1  | [2016-03-08 21:03:59 -0800] [8288] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
web.1  | [2016-03-08 21:04:00 -0800] [8288] [ERROR] Connection in use: ('0.0.0.0', 5000)
web.1  | [2016-03-08 21:04:00 -0800] [8288] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
web.1  | [2016-03-08 21:04:01 -0800] [8288] [ERROR] Connection in use: ('0.0.0.0', 5000)
```

Comment: seems like some other process is running on port 5000. Try to run your web app on a different port.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

#### This answer assumes you are running on a *nix machine like OSX or Linux.

```
kill `lsof -i :5000`
```

What this does is kill the process running on port 5000. You could also, if you wanted to see what was running on port 5000 run the following:

```
ps aux | grep 5000
```

That will show you the process running that match the string 5000 and you'll likely see what is causing that error. You could then `kill` that process id.

Another option is to run your app on a different port like so: `heroku local web --port 5001`

Comment: Changing the port did it for me. Strange as I run my local there, and yet there are actually other processes running there too that I don't control.
Guess I don't understand the workings underneath.